# Rails - using `url_for` with route path in email does not include host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

While not documented well nor shown in examples, `url_for` can be used with paths (e.g., `url_for(signup_path)` would produce `/signup`) vs controllers and actions.

However, in doing do it does not include the host if one set in corresponding environment file.

reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html

Why is this the behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the full URL, use:

```
url_for(signup_url)
```

From the Rails Guide on [route helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers):

> Each of these [`_path`] helpers has a corresponding `_url` helper (such as `photos_url`) which returns the same path prefixed with the current host, port and path prefix.

Comment: Awesome! I completely missed that... I thought `_ulr` and `_path` was only for root (`root_url` and `root_path`).

Answer (score 0):

Using url_for to generate a link in an email is probably not the way you want to go. In any case use signup_url not signup_path if you want the proper environment appended to the link.

```
<%= link_to "Signup", signup_url %>
```

Comment: Thanks Brady.. my question was in context of url_for within a link_to (i.e., within email). See @Substantial for the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by url_for within a link_to?